# Nesting informations into a Laravel 8 controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build an API for a platform similar to netflix using Laravel 8; everything works perfectly even the petitions with postman, the only problem I encounter is in the petition get through an id; so, for example, one of my routes is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/actors and if I try to do a petition using get method to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/actors/1 Postman returns me an error which in my opinion depends on how I nested the informations inside my ActorController file. So I wanted to ask you to take a look at my ActorController file which is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Actor;
use App\Models\Documentaryactor;
use App\Models\Fictionactor;
use App\Models\Kidactor;
use App\Models\Movieactor;
use App\Models\Originalactor;
use App\Models\Otheractor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class ActorController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $actors = Actor::all();
        return response()->json([
            "data" => $actors,
            "status" => Response::HTTP_OK
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $actor = Actor::create($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Actor has been successfully created",
            "data" => $actor,
            "status" => Response::HTTP_CREATED,
        ], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Actor  $actor
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Actor $actor)
    {
        $movieactor = Movieactor::findOrFail($actor->idMovie);
        $fictionactor = Fictionactor::findOrFail($actor->idFiction);
        $documentaryactor = Documentaryactor::findOrFail($actor->idDocumentary);
        $kidactor = Kidactor::findOrFail($actor->idKid);
        $originalactor = Originalactor::findOrFail($actor->idOriginal);
        $otheractor = Otheractor::findOrFail($actor->idOther);
        return response()->json([
            "actor" => $actor,
            "movieactor" => $movieactor,
            "fictionactor" => $fictionactor,
            "documentaryactor" => $documentaryactor,
            "kidactor" => $kidactor,
            "originalactor" => $originalactor,
            "otheractor" => $otheractor,
            "status" => Response::HTTP_OK,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Actor  $actor
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Actor $actor)
    {
        $actor->update($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Actor has been successfully updated",
            "data" => $actor,
            "status" => Response::HTTP_OK,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Actor  $actor
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Actor $actor)
    {
        $actor->delete();
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Actor has been successfully deleted",
            "data" => $actor,
            "status" => Response::HTTP_OK,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the show function, I tried to nest the informations coming from my other tables (specifically I created several pivot-tables to bind data together). For example, the documentary-actor pivot-table was created to bind together my actors table and my documentaries table.

I really cannot understand what I'm doing wrong and I thank in advance whoever will help me to understand it. If you need (perhaps to better understand my problem) that I attach other files, I will do it immediately.

Greetings

Alessandra

Comment: Please share the error response from Postman.

Comment: @jrcamatog First of all, thank you for your quick reply. The mistake that Postman retuens me it derives from an exception that I have personally set in my Handler.php file (which I attach below) and which literally says:

```
{
    "message": "We were unable to find the requested data",
    "status": 404
}

```

Comment: You can edit your post and paste the exception/other files there. :)

Comment: @jrcamatog Here, then,you can find my Handler.php file: [link](https://i.ibb.co/L6fJwYD/Handler.png)

Comment: So you have a model that you cant find clearly? in general i would not do multiple find or fails, these should be relationships.

Answer (score 0):

`findOrFail` throws an exception when it doesn't find the model. You can just use the `find` method so that it will just return `null` if the model is not found.

Another problem might be that the actor you're trying to fetch is missing.

```php
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Actor  $actor
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Actor $actor)
    {
        $movieactor = Movieactor::find($actor->idMovie);
        $fictionactor = Fictionactor::find($actor->idFiction);
        $documentaryactor = Documentaryactor::find($actor->idDocumentary);
        $kidactor = Kidactor::find($actor->idKid);
        $originalactor = Originalactor::find($actor->idOriginal);
        $otheractor = Otheractor::find($actor->idOther);
        return response()->json([
            "actor" => $actor,
            "movieactor" => $movieactor,
            "fictionactor" => $fictionactor,
            "documentaryactor" => $documentaryactor,
            "kidactor" => $kidactor,
            "originalactor" => $originalactor,
            "otheractor" => $otheractor,
            "status" => Response::HTTP_OK,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Comment: I tried to replace findOrFail with find but now Postman does not to the petition anymore